# Django dynamic url in root domain overwrites all other urls

Tags: django, url, redirect, dynamic, dns

I want to have a dynamic root url for different users. All users get their own url. I want to have the dynamic url in the root but also be able to have more hardcoded urls as alternatives, for example on the url that the user will edit their profile.

The problem i have is that all urls redirect to view2 and none goes to view1.

```
path(r'edit/<str:user>/', views.view1, name='view1'),
path(r'<str:user>/', views.view2, name='view2'),
```

*example.com/edit/user* always gets redirected to *example.com/user* which is not wanted.

views:

```
def viewID(request):
    return render(request, 'viewID.html')
```

Comment: Can you share your views.py with your def view1() and def view2() functions?

Comment: dont think it matters right? Updated the question =)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

urls.py:

```
path('edit/<str:user>/', views.view1, name='view1'),
path('<str:user>/', views.view2, name='view2'),
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def view1(request, user):
        return HttpResponse('This is view1: ' + user)
    
    
  def view2(request, user):
        return HttpResponse('This is view2: ' + user)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was quite frustrating. I needed to clear the cache or run in a private window since django kept appending a "/" to example.com/user/ which of course would go to view1 since it exects a key